# why should i create a view model in ionic 3?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

well i dont understand if i am doing something wrong with my models or its just that i dont understand it well enough , i am creating apps with ionic 3 in which i am creating view models for the data coming from the api i am consuming.

so say i have a get request that is getting a list of items and i have an interface for an item like so

```
export interface Item{
    item_ID:number;
    item_Name:string;
}
```

having an api that will get items in the above format and subscribing to the get request will return the data in the item object i showed above and i can access the properties normally , what i dont get tho is if i change the return data from the api , for example adding item_price to the returned json from the api and assigning the data returned to the interface object will just add the property to it anyway regardless of my definition , am i doing something wrong here ? or am i missing something ?

thanks in advance !

Comment: The interface is to help with type safety in TypeScript. It will not change the shape of the data objects to match the interface.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel from what you are saying i am getting that i should be defining it as a class not an interface? i was following along with a course that taught ionic and this was the way it created the view models i didnt understand it so thats why i asked. thanks for your help !

Comment: Point 4 - https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-03-03 advices on using Interfaces for Datamodels instead of classes.

Comment: @EssamEid if you don't want to keep all of the properties on the objects returned from your service, the best thing would be to use the RxJS `map` operator to mutate the objects to the shape that you want. Classes vs Interfaces will not change your behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript only adds type safety during compile-time (well, type-check time). Basically, if you do

```
const a: string = 1 + 2
```

TypeScript will scream at you but it will still produce the following valid JavaScript:

```
const a = 1 + 2
```

Browser will happily assign `3` to `a` -- it doesn't care, or even *know* that you declared is as a string in TypeScript code. The only thing your browsers sees is JavaScript, and there is no way to define static types in JavaScript, since it's a loosely-typed language.

In your example, you try to teach TypeScript what the resonse will look like, so you say that it will have `item_ID` and `item_Name`. But when TypeScript is compiled to JavaScript, this information will be lost -- JavaScript will accept any sort of object and won't care for what interface you've used in TypeScript.

In order words, doing this:

```
const respose: MyInterface = await fetch('data').somehow()
```

means that *you* are sure that the API endpoint will return a shape of `MyInterface` -- if it doesn't, TypeScript cannot help you. Hence, if you API doesn't return `MyInterface`, but something else, nothing will change in your code and when you `console.log` the returned value, you'll see it for what it is (what the API returned), and not for what you specified via an interface.